# What is a DLM upstart job and how to start it in order to run displaylink successfully?

Tags: upstart, displaylink

I know displaylink is now available for ubuntu 16.04. So I bought an AOC usb monitor, and I was trying to install the driver following the instruction of his link:

http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu

After I run

```
sudo ./displaylink-driver-1.2.65.run
```

which is the last step of the installation according to the link, I got the following messages in the terminal

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 1.2.65  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 1.2.65 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Installing EVDI kernel module to kernel tree 
EVDI kernel module built successfully
Installing x64-ubuntu-1604/DisplayLinkManager
Installing libraries
Installing firmware packages
Installing license file
Adding udev rule for DisplayLink DL-3xxx/5xxx devices
Warning: dlm.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units
```

Everything looks good until the last two lines. According to the link, what you should get is

```
Adding udev rule for DisplayLink DL-3xxx/5xxx devices
Starting DLM upstart job
displaylink start/running, process 3397
```

Apparently, there is something wrong, because the graphics can only be displayed on my AOC monitor for 5 seconds, then I got error message saying that Ubuntu encountered an internal error. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: 16.04 uses systemd, not upstart. Try `systemctl status dlm`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it, but still my ubuntu cannot detect the second monitor.